# Move a screen from one virtual desktop to the other

Tags: windows, virtual-desktop, sysinternals

I'm using the "Desktops" program by sysinternals. I'm wondering if it's possible to move a screen to one of the other virtual desktops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No it's not. From its webpage at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881.aspx.

> Desktops reliance on Windows desktop objects means that it cannot provide some of the functionality of other virtual desktop utilities, however. For example, Windows doesn't provide a way to move a window from one desktop object to another.

You can use other virtual desktop programs though.

Comment: where is it suggested above?

Comment: It's not any more! I don't remember, but I guess someone deleted their answer...

Comment: @NathanFellman what are you talking about. The quote he gives states clearly "Windows doesn't provide a way to move a window from one desktop object to another."  Maybe you mean that the quote doesn't suggest that "You can use other virtual desktop programs".